# How to display a flash message on Rails using jQuery (SJR)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I am a beginner at web development and jQuery.

I would like a flash message to pop out on the screen when a new message is created. With the code below, a new chat message pops out on the screen when created without reloading. The flash message, however, does not appear at the same time the chat message gets created.

Does anyone know how to deal with this issue? Any advice would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

My first language is not English, so if you have any questions or this post does not make sense, let me know!

Here is my code.

`message/create.js.erb`

```
$("#message_body").val("");
$("ul").html("<%=j(render @messages) %>");
$("#layout-notice").html("<%=j flash[:notice] %>");
```

`messages_controller.rb`

```
def index
  @messages = @chat_group.messages
  @message = Message.new
end

def create
  @message = Message.new(message_params)
  @message.chat_group = @chat_group
  @message.user = current_user
  # @message.save

  if @message.save
    flash[:notice] = 'successfully sent'
  else
    flash[:notice] = 'Unfortunately failed to sent'
  end

  @messages = @chat_group.messages.all
end
```

`messasges/index.html.haml`

```
 - if user_signed_in?
   = form_for @message, :url => {:action => :index}, remote: true do |f|
   = f.text_field :body
   = f.submit 'send'
  %ul
   = render @messages
   = link_to "sign out", destroy_user_session_path, method: :delete
  - else
   %h1 you need to log in
   = link_to "sign in", user_session_path, method: :post
```

Comment: You can use `toastr-rails` gem for displaying flash messages in JS. For more details visit https://github.com/tylergannon/toastr-rails.

Comment: Thank you Uday. I will give it a shot.

Answer (score 0):

## How flash works

The Rails flash is set up to allow you to store data to utilize *on the next request* (meaning after a redirect has occurred and a new request cycle has started).

From the [Action Controller Overview - Ruby on Rails Guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#the-flash)

> By default, adding values to the flash will make them available to the next request, but sometimes you may want to access those values in the same request ... To do this, you can use `flash.now`

When you are responding with JS, there is no redirect after the request finishes. This means that putting stuff in the flash during a JS request will make it available to *the next request only*.

So, **in order to use a flash message *within the same request*, you have to use `flash.now`**

## Using `flash.now`

You use `flash.now` in exactly the same way as the regular flash.

In your case

```
if @message.save
  flash.now[:notice] = 'successfully sent'
else
  flash.now[:notice] = 'Unfortunately failed to sent'
end
```

## Additional Resources

- http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Flash/FlashHash.html#method-i-now
- http://ionrails.com/2009/09/19/flashnotice-vs-flash-nownotice/
- http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#the-flash

Comment: Thank you very much for your tip, Carlos. However, your suggested codes does not work... Do you have any idea why?

Comment: When you say it's not working, what specifically are you seeing? Is there an error message? Does the flash message still show up blank? Let me know exactly what you are seeing and we can debug.

Comment: My apologies. The flash message does not come out on the screen at the same time as the message gets created.

Comment: Try adding this to the top of your js.erb file: `alert("<%= j flash[:notice] %>");` so we can see if your flash is being set properly. Remove all the other code temporarily except for that alert.

Comment: `alert("<%= j flash[:notice] %>");` comes out properly, I mean, when a new message gets created.

Comment: In that case the message is there but your problem may be in how you are trying to add it to the DOM. Is `$("#layout-notice").html("<%=j flash[:notice] %>");` definitely the right code? Try adding it to the body `$(body).append("<%= j flash[:notice] %>")`

Comment: still does not pop out on the screen.... `$("#layout-notice").html("<%=j flash[:notice] %>");` is just a code written for the test.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127537/discussion-between-carlos-ramirez-iii-and-azure1015).

Answer (score 0):

**Manufactures Controller Action Create:**

```
  def create
    @manufacture = Manufacture.new(manufacture_params)
    respond_to do |format|
      if @manufacture.save
        format.js { flash.now[:notice] = "Manufacture was successfully created." }
      else
        format.html { redirect_to manufactures_url, alert: @manufacture.errors.full_messages }
      end
    end
  end
```

**views/manufactures/index.html.erb**

```
<div id="flash-message">
</div>
```

**views/manufactures/create.js.erb**

```
$("#flash-message").html("<%= j render partial: "shared/message"%>");
```

**Add this file: views/shared/_message.html.erb**

```
<% if notice %>
  <div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissible fade show col-4 mx-auto mt-5" role="alert">
    <h4><%= notice %></h4>
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
      <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
    </button>
  </div>
<% end %>
<% if alert %>
  <div class="alert alert-warning alert-dismissible fade show col-4 mx-auto mt-5" role="alert">
    <h4><%= alert %></h4>
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
      <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
    </button>
  </div>
<% end %>
```